# Javascript Url Replace

Tags: javascript

So currently, I have my url like this: `http://localhost:8000/fund_monitor/fund_details/fundaccountid=4&transmission=3&startDate=2017-08-01&endDate=2017-08-02/`

Then when I redirect the url using `windows.location.replace(url)`, the url becomes like this: `http://localhost:8000/fund_monitor/fund_details/fundaccountid%3D4&transmission%3D3&startDate%3D2017-08-01&endDate%3D2017-08-02/`

So the equal sign gets converted to another format. Is there a way to retain the original format?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem to cause an issue for me on Chrome latest. Which browser are you using?

Comment: well why is it not a querystring? It is being urlencoded....

Comment: I am using Chrome :/

Comment: does it do the same i you use `windows.location.href = url;`?

Comment: Shouldn't the url be `http://localhost:8000/fund_monitor/fund_details/?fundaccountid=4&transmission=3&startDate=2017-08-01&endDate=2017-08-02/` (notice the `?` separating the path from the data) or something like that? Special characters like `=` and `&` are not allowed as is in the path, that's why they get encoded, but they are **expected** in the query string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be because the URL is not in a valid format. It's format is roughly `protocol://host:port/path?query_params`[1], where `query_params` looks like `a=1&b=2` etc. But you do need the `?` to separate the path from your parameters. Whatever you're using seems to treat the part `fundaccountid=4&transmission=3&startDate=2017-08-01&endDate=2017-08-02/` as a path, and url encodes it so it can be a proper path. Perhaps try to write the URL as: `http://localhost:8000/fund_monitor/fund_details?fundaccountid=4&transmission=3&startDate=2017-08-01&endDate=2017-08-02`
and see if that works.

Though it will mean some changes to your backend.

---

[1] The full format you can see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) or [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

> The decodeURIComponent() function decodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component previously created by encodeURIComponent or by a similar routine.

```js
var url = 'http://localhost:8000/fund_monitor/fund_details/fundaccountid%3D4&transmission%3D3&startDate%3D2017-08-01&endDate%3D2017-08-02/';

console.log(decodeURIComponent(url));
```

Comment: Good and reliable answer

Comment: This is sort of the reverse of the correct answer. He wants to know why his URL is being encoded, not how to encode it.

Comment: @torazaburo Just attached the wrong description. The code snippet was correct to get the decoded URL but its explanation was wrong. Corrected it. Thanks for pointing out.